# How to record a thickbox using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

Is there any way to record a thickbox using selenium IDE?

The [thickbox](http://thickbox.net/) which I am trying to record is developed using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

A JQuery thickbox is simply some JavaScript that generates simple HTML elements and renders them in the browser.  Selenium IDE should have no problem recording any of those.  What specific challenges are you running into?  Are you getting specific exceptions or error messages?

Comment: It is showing the error as "Element TB_iframeContent706 not found" while I am opening the edit box and recording in selenium IDE

Comment: Ah... is the element inside an iframe?  I'm familiar with how to handle iframes in Selenium2/Webdriver but not selenium RC/IDE.  See selectFrame here: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html